# Annotate a Java constructor as implementing a @FunctionalInterface

Tags: java, lambda, constructor, warnings, functional-interface

I would like to use this functional interface from Spring:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface RowMapper<T> {
    T mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException;
}
```

Here is a way to use it by explicitly declaring a RowMapper constant that will just call the constructor:

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, parameters, ValueObject.ROW_MAPPER);

public class ValueObject {
    public static final RowMapper<ValueObject> ROW_MAPPER = (resultSet, rowNum) -> new ValueObject(resultSet);

    public final long field;

    public ValueObject(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        field = resultSet.getLong("FIELD");
    }
}
```

You see: I don't use the rowNum argument.

I'd like to have a more concise and expressive code.
I'd like to use the constructor directly without having to declare a RowMapper:

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, parameters, ValueObject::new);

public class ValueObject {
    public final long field;

    public ValueObject(ResultSet resultSet, int unusedRowNumFromRowMapperInterface) throws SQLException {
        field = resultSet.getLong("FIELD");
    }
}
```

A lot cleaner, but the IDE and Sonar now complain about the unused parameter.

I could add @SuppressWarnings({"unused", "java:S1172"}) to that parameter.
But that would pollute the clean solution:
I don't want other developers on the project blindly copy/paste this vaudou incantation for each and every ValueObject they create.
And I don't want them to create a constant + a constructor boilerplate neither.

Is there a way to inform the compiler that the constructor is in fact implementing the RowMapper @FunctionalInterface, so that it knows the second argument is required, even if unused?

Or another less direct way to cleanly get rid of the warning?

I tried to create this annotation to annotate the unused parameter with a meaningful name, encapsulating the implementation details of removing the warnings, but this does not work either:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Inherited
@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "java:S1172"})
public @interface ThisParameterIsFromRowMapperInterface {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Annotate a Java constructor as implementing a @FunctionalInterface

That's like asking 'Add a corner to the colour green'. it makes no sense whatsoever.

The point of FunctionalInterface is to mark an interface as **defining** a 'function', in the sense that you can write a lambda syntax (`(a, b) -> result`) or method reference construct (`foo::bar`) in a place where a value of that interface is required, and then javac will automatically fix things for you so that it works.

You don't annotate a method (or constructor) that fits the pattern and could be used as a method reference.

> A lot cleaner, but the IDE and Sonar now complain about the unused parameter.

Have you heard the parable about the doctor?

A patient asked the doctor: "Doctor, it hurts when I press here!"

The doctor said: "Okay. Well, stop doing that then!"

The problem is your IDE/Sonar, and not your code. Turn that 'checker' / 'linter' feature off, it is silly, and is off by default so somebody turned it on, thinking (erroneously) that this is a useful check.

There is a proper version of this check: If and only if the linter tool has a full view of the entire method hierarchy (so not just the method itself, but all methods that override it, all methods that this method is overriding, and all external-to-this-codebase methods that may override it in the future), and the parameter is ignored for *all* those methods, *then* it is okay to warn about it.

Given that linters don't have a crystal ball, it starts with ensuring the method is either effectively `final` or effectively (package) private, so as to reduce the set of unknowable externals to 0. The check cannot apply to any non-final public anything: Perhaps that parameter exists for the benefit of the code that will override this method. (Think about it: When you have an `abstract` method, all parameters are 'ignored' as there is no code at all!)

Had that more intelligent take been enabled, no warning would have occurred here: lambdas override something, by definition.

> Is there a way to inform the compiler that the constructor is in fact implementing the RowMapper @FunctionalInterface, so that it knows the second argument is required, even if unused?

There is not. You could make a second constructor that takes a second parameter (of type `int`), only for it to completely ignore this parameter, but that **would** in fact trigger that linter warning if it's an intelligent linting, as constructors by definition cannot be overriding something and cannot be overridden, thus qualifying for the 'ignored parameter' check as being useful, isn't that ironic?

I strongly advise against making a constructor which effectively needs the following javadoc:

```
/**
 * This constructor completely ignores the second parameter.
 * It is intended to be used in the form of `MyType::new`,
 * when you need a `RowMapper`.
 * <strong>NB: Any other use is neccessarily a bug</strong>.
 */
```

Because, well, read it. Putting bolded warnings to explain that the intended use of a thing is surprising is bad: You don't want surprises in your code base, and you don't want methods that are likely to be misunderstood without reading the docs.

> I tried to create this annotation to annotate the unused parameter with a meaningful name, encapsulating the implementation details of removing the warnings, but this does not work either

That doesn't work; annotations do not 'meta' like this. You can annotate an annotation definition but that doesn't mean 'annotating a thing with this annotation implies the thing is annotated with all these annotations'. It can mean that, but only if an annotation (and the associated tools!) are defined to work like that, because it's not built into java. `@SuppressWarnings` doesn't work that way.

### Okay, so what *do* I do in this situation?

I suggest you try something like this:

```
public class WhateverYouHaveThere {
    public static RowMapper asRowMapper() {
        return (rs, idx) -> new WhateverYouHaveThere(rs);
    }
}
```

This method needs no javadoc and no comments: The name of the method + the `static` modifier covers 100% of its purpose, and the implementation is not surprising in the slightest.

And then, of course, fix the boneheaded setting in your linter :) – the fact that it would warn on this method is proof enough it's just getting in the way and not giving you any meaningful insights in suspect code.

It then lets you write:

```
public static final RowMapper<ValueObject> ROW_MAPPER = ValueObject.asRowMapper();
```

NB: You can make this a static field as well:

```
public class ValueObject {
    public static final RowMapper<ValueObject> ROW_MAPPER =
      (rs, idx) -> new ValueObject(rs);
}
```

But I wouldn't. More of a style thing. A lot of the argument in favour of getters over public final fields apply here as well. Basically: Give yourself more flexibility in the future to add logging, change implementations, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer: I fully agree!

Yes, warnings are only hints.
But they are also incredibly useful in other cases.
In this case, if I'm about to recommend a solution for the whole project, I'd like to not contain any borderline fragile construct.
Here, the warning points toward a strange/fragile design where every developer would once in a while remove that parameter, only to discover it's needed, or name it differently and leave no clue to why it is here.

I was not aware of "prefer static methods instead of static fields": I'll try to apply this more often.

Comment: You made me think about another variation of asRowMapper.
I added a detailed reply to the question.
Your asRowMapper() is like the static field I was using: this boilerplate needs to be in every class: I moved to one central place.

Comment: _But they are also incredibly useful in other cases._ Not this one. The 'intelligent' unused parameter check (which triggers only on both-ways-private/within-project-under-linting method signatures) is useful. The blanket one just aint. It's not even 'borderline', __It is a useless check__, turn it off. _Here, the warning points toward a strange/fragile design where every developer would once in a while remove that parameter_ That is inherent in the design of lambdas. The community at large has embraced it; you use code from the community; you have to live with this. A linter cannot help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rzwitserloot for his detailed answer.
He made me think about another variation of asRowMapper:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface SimpleRowMapper<T> {
    T mapRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
}

public class RowMapperUtil {
    public static <T> RowMapper<T> asRowMapper(SimpleRowMapper<T> mapper) {
        return (resultSet, rowNum) -> mapper.mapRow(resultSet);
    }
}

namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, parameters, asRowMapper(ValueObject::new));
```

The constructor is not tied to one usage: it can be reused for other purposes (being another @FunctionalInterface or not), is clean, and asRowMapper is not to be copy/pasted/adapted for every ValueObject (and if we add logging or other concerns to the method, we can do that at a single place).

The only downside is that it's an Util class: these classes can easily proliferate with a lot of unrelated methods, all of which suffering from the "Feature Envy" code smell.

To solve that, it's always a good idea to encapsulate our dependencies into interfaces/classes we own, so we can tailor them to the usages of our project.
It would mean encapsulating NamedParameterJdbcTemplate into a sort of proxy class we own, and on which we can add our own method taking a SimpleRowMapper parameter:

```
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, SqlParameterSource paramSource, SimpleRowMapper<T> rowMapper) throws DataAccessException { ... }
```

That way, we can keep the constructor with only one parameter and still use it without asRowMapper():

```
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, parameters, ValueObject::new);
```

And/or, ask Spring to include this new method to their own NamedParameterJdbcTemplate if they think the use case is important enough to support.